# Lync API for VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel, lync

I need to send instant messages automatically from excel. I know how to do it, but I have a problem with Lync API. I have Office 2010 and Lync 2013 and I cannot find  in references in VBA editor anything related to Lync or Communicator. I went through all pages and I find almost impossible to solve this and find correct API to use. I downloaded from MSDN portal communicatorAPI.dll, but it is not working. Do you know how to solve this? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Give us a link to the  Lync library itself.

Comment: I don´t have it and neither found it. Everything related to this topic I found, is about Office Communicator. So i also installed Office Communicator just to have this API, and this is working, but the problem is that only with Communicator, not with Lync :( I also reinstalled Lync, but it seems that for Lync there is really nothing. SO right now I am thinking, if it could be done somehow with this "Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 API Type Library" for Lync.